# Why when I perform this JavaScript statment that create a new Number object (using the new operator) the result is different in Chrome and FireFox?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I am pretty new in JavaScript and I have the following doubt: I am doing some experiment with **built in funcion constructor** concept.

So I a trying to build a new **Number** object using the **new** operator.

If I open Chrome Developer Tools, and in the **Console** I perform this statment:

```
var a = new Number(3);
undefined
a;
Number {[[PrimitiveValue]]: 3}
```

as you can see first I create a new **Number** object using the **new** operator and then I perform this object and I obtain its value: **Number {[[PrimitiveValue]]: 3}**

The problem is that if I do the same thing into **FireBug** inside **FireFox** I obtain something different, I obtain this:

```
var a = new Number(3);
undefined
a;
Number {}
```

So, using **FireFox**, doing the same thing, it seems that create the **Number** object but that this object is empty and don't contain the **3** value as done in **Chrome**.

Why? How is it possible? What am I missing?

Another doubt is related about how exactly works the previous object creation, when I perform:

```
var a = new Number(3);
```

Ok, I am using the **function contructure** concept associate to the **new** operator. From what I know (but correct me if I am doing wrong assertion), when I perform a function using the **new** operator happens that:

1. It is created a new empty object. So in this case it is created a new **Number** object that should means a JavaScript object that have the **proto** variable setted to the reference of the **Number** object, so this object will have access to all the methods deffined for **Number** (following the prototypal inheritence concept implemented by JavaScript).
2. The **this** variable putted into the execution context of this function is setted to the reference of the new created object.
3. The parameter is used to set the object property. So in this case the value will be 3.

Why when I do:

```
var a = new Number(3);
```

I obtain the **undefined** value? It could depends by the fact that this **Number** function do not return any value?

Is it my reasoning correct or am I missing something?

Comment: The best way to understand this would be to look at the JavaScript specification for the Number type. I haven't read it in a while, but as I understand it there was a bit of room for interpretation when implementing primitive types like this. Just be aware that there is a difference in the higher-level concept of the primitive types being Object instances and the actual implementation.

Comment: Because don't do that. In JavaScript you shouldn't ever need to use the Number constructor. Just declare `var a = 3;` and you're done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since Niet already  answered about different console implementation in different ways.

This part of your assertion is wrong

> It is created a new empty object. So in this case it is created a new
>   Number object that should means a JavaScript object that have the
>   proto variable setted to the reference of the Number object, so this
>   object will have access to all the methods deffined for Number

the `__proto__`(non-standard) will be set to `Number.prototype` not `Number`.

Comment: Ok, because Number.prototype what exactly contains? all the methods that a Number can use?

Comment: `Number.prototype` is the actual object , your object inherits properties from . all the methods like `toFixed()` come from that

Comment: I have understand that my a object inherit from the Number.prototype. But why from it and not from Number? What contains?

Comment: `Number` is just a function(itself an object), it use it's `prototype`(not `__proto__`) to set up  the `__proto__` link of the object , when objects are created. read this great article : http://www.pixelstech.net/article/1330336522-Prototypes-and-Inheritance-in-JavaScript

Answer (score 5):

The way that objects are presented in the console is implementation-specific. While Chrome reveals the number's value, that's nothing to do with the actual object itself, but rather how Chrome spits it back out.

You will notice that `a.valueOf()` will return `3` in both cases.

As an aside, IE displays: `[object Number] {}`